# Icons for Drop-down Menu and Sidebar Minimizer disappeared

Tags: html, css

So I'm not the most familiar with HTML, but I know enough to make very minor tweaks.

I had this issue all of a sudden where I updated my github page website, and a few icons were missing.

Sidebar toggle(top right of pic) and sub-menu dropdown chevrons:

[image: sidebar]

Envelope icons next to email addresses:

[image: email]

The little icons for the sidebar minimizer, dropdown menu, and the "envelope" icons used to represent emails disappeared.

I redownloaded the template I built my website on just to check if I did something wrong: https://html5up.net/editorial

But even in the newly downloaded file, those icons were missing, whereas when I first downloaded them, they weren't

Given that this issue also happened in a freshly downloaded template (but as you see on the website preview the icons are fine), I'm baffled as to what the issue might be.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

The icons missing are F0C9, F078 and F0E0.

Comment: can't see icon on left menu of your link

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/e8faa62fb1511835f4af47be70b98ce9.png Can you see the 3 bars on the top right that toggle the side bar, and the dropdown chevrons that indicate submenus? Those are missing in my pages.

Comment: i see this https://ibb.co/DVg4gwn

Comment: You're seeing it right then. i edited the main post for clarity.

Comment: Maybe you're missing correct class names. I've just checked by simply replacing **content** in Firefox inspect elements tools and it work fine. i Can see 3 icon which you told are missing. Be sure to include theme correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are includes via FontAwesome, so either you forgot to include FontAwesome or moved the files. Make sure there is a `fontawesome-all.min.css` in your `/css` folder and the corresponding `webfonts` folder exists and contains the FontAwesome-files